# how to not remove apostrophe only for some words in text file in python

Tags: python, regex

In a sentence, How can I remove apostrophe, double quotes, comma and so on for all words excluding words like it's, what's etc.. and at end of the sentence there must be a space between word and full stop.

For example

Input Sentence :

```
"'This has punctuation, and it's hard to remove. ?"
```

Desired Output Sentence :

```
This has punctuation and it's hard to remove .
```

Comment: Can you provide more examples please and define 'etc' more clearly?

Comment: If I have sentence like below example I want to remove all punctuations except words like it's, what's and need space between word and period at end of the line.                                                          INPUT File : "'I bought this for $30 from Best Buy it's.
What a waste of money! The ear gels are 'comfortable at first, but what's after an hour.
Desired Output:                                                     I bought this for 30 from Best Buy it's .
What a waste of money The ear gels are comfortable at first but what's after an hour.

Comment: Can you put that in your question and format it appropriately? Some edge case scenarios you might not have considered: What if you have `Did you see Cress' haircut?` `This 'thing' has a really bad habit, you know?` What should those become?

Comment: Input sentence:                                                    Did you see Cress' haircut?.                                       This 'thing' hasn't a really bad habit, you know?.             Desired Output :                                                 Did you see Cress haircut .                                       This thing hasn't a really bad habit, you know .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this code:

```
import re

sentences = [""""'This has punctuation, and it's hard to remove. ?" """,
             "Did you see Cress' haircut?.",
             "This 'thing' hasn't a really bad habit, you know?.",
             "'I bought this for $30 from Best Buy it's. What a waste of money! The ear gels are 'comfortable at first, but what's after an hour."]

for s in sentences:
    # Remove the specified characters
    new_s = re.sub(r"""["?,$!]|'(?!(?<! ')[ts])""", "", s)

    # Deal with the final dot
    new_s = re.sub(r"\.", " .", new_s)
    print(new_s)
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/dNwwVG)

Output:

```
This has punctuation and it's hard to remove .
Did you see Cress haircut .
This thing hasn't a really bad habit you know .
I bought this for 30 from Best Buy it's . What a waste of money The ear gels are comfortable at first but what's after an hour .
```

---

The regex:

```
["?,$!]     # Match " ? , $ or !
|           # OR
'           # A ' if it does not have...
(?!        
  (?<! ')  
  [ts]      # t or s after it, provided it has no ` '` before the t or s
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jerry, But how to remove apostrophe for below words          Cress' = Cress

Comment: @user3232688 Oh oops. Somehow I thought it should be kept. Give me a few minutes to fix this. Ok, changed.

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative look-behind

```
(?<!\w)["'?]|,(?= )
```

REmove the matched `'"?` characters through `re.sub`.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wY8kG1/4)

And your code would be,

```
>>> s = '\"\'This has punctuation, and it\'s hard to remove. ?\" '
>>> m = re.sub(r'(?<!\w)[\"\'\?]|,(?= )', r'', s)
>>> m
"This has punctuation and it's hard to remove.  "
```

Comment: comma is missing. `"'This' has` the second apostrophe will not included in regex.

Comment: @Braj i think now, it's ok.

Comment: This would leave the `?` in `OK?` (for instance—it would also leave the comma in `car,` etc), don't know if that's alright with the OP?

Answer (score 0):

Use the string.strip(delimiter) function for the outside quotes

like this :

```
output = chaine.strip("\"")
```

Be careful, you have to escape some characters with a '\' like ', ", \, and so on. Or you can enter them as "'", '"' (unsure).

Edit : mmh, didn't think about the apostrophes, if the only problem is the apostrophes you can strip the rest first then parse it manually with a for statement, place indice of first apostrophe found then if followed by an 's', leave it, I don't know, you have to set lexical/semantical rules before coding it.

Edit 2 :
If the string is only a sentence, and always has a dot at the end, and always needs the space, then use this at the end :

```
chaine[:-2]+" "+chaine[-2:]
```

Comment: `strip` will only work for removing leading and trailing characters.

Comment: Edited my answer, but not sure if the quotation marks are part of the input, I think so because they aren't in the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
(?<![tT](?=.[sS]))["'?:;,.]
```

If you also want to leave the period at the end of a line (as long as it is preceded by a space):

```
(?<![tT](?=.[sS]))(?<! (?=.$))["'?:;,.]
```

Comment: FYI, to get it right is a bit more complex than it sounds, that's why my regex is a bit longer. Added a second version that leaves the period at the end of a line (if preceded by a space.)

Answer (score 0):

My take for this is, remove all quotations which are at either end of a word. So split the sentences to word (separated by white-space) and strip any leading or trailing quotation marks from the words

```
>>> ''.join(e.strip(string.punctuation) for e in re.split("(\s)",st))
"This has punctuation and it's hard to remove   "
```

Comment: Still has `punctuation,`, the OP wants to remove the `,`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I had initially shown the approach. What ever you want to strip, you need to add an explicit list. In this particular case, I have included `string.punctuation`

Comment: @Abhijit How to keep space between word and period at end of the file and can you please let me know if an input sentence is like below .                                                             "'I bought this for $30 from Best Buy it's.                         What a waste of money! The ear are 'comfortable at first, but what's after an hour                                                Desired output must be like : I bought this for 30 from Best Buy it's .
What a waste of money The ear are comfortable at first, but what's after an hour or so, your ear starts to really hurt from it .